# how to search lyric for an audio file (and then return a variable of type string) in windows 8 C# app?

Tags: c#, windows-8

I'm intending to develop a music player windows 8 app. I want my app to include the function that automatically search for the lyric of the current playing audio file. I have no idea about how to do this. 
I would appreciate if any one can show me the way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to search for the lyrics online from your application. Once you load up the audio file, you search through a couple of sites by providing them with the audio name. You grab the results returned by their search and see if it contains some lyrics for you. There can be multiple results, so you have to choose between one of them. Then you grab the source of that specific result and parse the lyric and display it in your application. For example:

[Call Me Maybe - Lyrics](http://www.lyrics.com/call-me-maybe-lyrics-carly-rae-jepsen.html)

In the link:  **call-me-maybe-lyrics-carly-rae-jepsen** will be replaced by your audio name and then you simply append **.html** and grab the source code of the page and see if there are any lyrics.
You can do this in parallel for many sites and select the best match to display.